# Adding a custom attribute to an HTML Element from server side C#

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html

I recently added a custom attribute to a DIV that works well with IE but not in Chrome with a typical message of UNDEFINED. Here my code.

Server Side

```
    public void Bind()
    {
        myDiv.Attributes.Add("data", TextBox1.Text);
    }
```

Client Side

```
<div id="myDiv" runat="server" class="class1">
</div>
```

Javascript

```
alert(($('[id$=myDiv]')[0]).data);
```

Comment: Try using a `data-` attribute instead... like `data-value` or `data-whatever`, then use `$('[id$=myDiv]').data('value')` or `$('[id$=myDiv]').data('whatever')` respectively.

Comment: @JasonP, It worked man! Thanks a lot!!! You must submit your comment as an "Answer" to vote for it!

Comment: on a side note.. why don't you use class instead of id ".class1"? its much cleaner.